# how to add alertcondition when the moving average color change when the direction change

Tags: alert, moving-average

I just learn how to write the pine script to change color of the hull moving average when the slope direction change. But I don't know how to add alertcondition when the color change. Can someone show me what to do? thanks

```
here is my pine script:
//@version=4
//Color MA colors the moving average plot based on fcvgn bjmh
study(title = "HMA7", shorttitle="H7", overlay = true)

//1a red
H1a = input(20, minval=1, title='1a')
src1a = input(close, title="Source")
hull1a = wma(2*wma(src1a, H1a/2)-wma(src1a, H1a), round(sqrt(H1a)))

avg1a = hull1a
Pcolor1a = avg1a > avg1a[1] ? color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0) : color.rgb(46, 109,255, 0)
plot(avg1a,title='1a', color=Pcolor1a, linewidth=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the code below. I commented out some sections to explain what was added

```
//@version=4
//Color MA colors the moving average plot based on fcvgn bjmh
study(title = "HMA7", shorttitle="H7", overlay = true)

// I used var to set the colors as constant values here. 
// A helpful tip would also be to change these to inputs so they can be adjusted in the menu
var col1 = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
var col2 = color.rgb(46, 109,255, 0)

///1a red
H1a = input(20, minval=1, title='1a')
src1a = input(close, title="Source")
hull1a = wma(2*wma(src1a, H1a/2)-wma(src1a, H1a), round(sqrt(H1a)))

avg1a = hull1a
Pcolor1a = avg1a > avg1a[1] ? col1 : col2
plot(avg1a,title='1a', color=Pcolor1a, linewidth=4)

// alerts

// here we check what our color variable was, and is equal to
// the == opertor can be used to check what something is equal to rather than assiging it value
// the [x] operator is used for historical reference. We use it here to check 1 bar ago
// so we check that the color is the first color and that it was not equal to that color 1 bar ago 
bullcon = Pcolor1a == col1 and (Pcolor1a != col1)[1]
bearcon = Pcolor1a == col2 and (Pcolor1a != col2)[1]

// I like to use something like plotshape() or plotchar() to verify the condition for the alert
// This way we can see it visually, confirm it will work, and delete it after 

plotshape(bullcon, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.belowbar, color=Pcolor1a)
plotshape(bearcon, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=Pcolor1a)

alertcondition(bullcon, title='Bullish Change', message='Bullish Color Change on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')
```

I added a plotshape function to visualize your alert. You can save this for future use and delete.

Cheers my friend and best of luck with your coding and trading!

Comment: Processing script...
Script could not be translated from: |B|var col1 = color.rgb(255,
Script 'H1 alert' has been saved

Comment: I got this error message after I copy your script into the pine editor, what might be wrong, I guess it is some small error, thanks for your help anyway, I still have a lot of thing to learn in this.

Comment: Make sure you have the version 4 at the top

Comment: Im sorry my friend!! Its my first week on Stack and I messed up the formatting in the paste box ^^^

Comment: I edited the original post and you should be good to go. To summarize the problem, there was an extra / in front of version 4 which meant it was trying to compile in version 2